# Transform RGB or HSL in a relevant number

Tags: javascript, python, c++, math, image-processing

I'll do an example to better understand what's the desired output.

```
colorRgb1 = [0, 150, 0]
colorRgb2 = [150, 0, 0]
```

What I want is to transform these type of arrays into a relevant number, in which each value(r,g,b) have the same weight and importance.

For a search color, like

```
searchColor = [0,140,0]
```

If I apply the same formula and obtain a number, this number to be closest to the number for `colorRgb1` rather then the number for `colorRgb2`

Comment: Can you show your code you have written? Also at StackOverflow please don't select multiple languages when they are not relevant to the question. That will only get you downvotes.

Comment: Now I see. I selected multiple languages because it was not a problem in a specific language, but something general. I don't have any code written. This is the problem and I'm looking for a solution

Comment: You seem to be asking for an injective mapping from 3d space to 1d space that preserves some notion of "closeness". I don't think such a thing is possible, for any plausible definition of "close".

Comment: If you do find a good, genetic solution to this problem, you’ll be famous. Good luck! :)